# TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am doing a school project but ran into some problems with tensor flow.
My `x_factors` is a pandas DataFrame with columns of dtypes either float64 or int64.

Attached is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_factors, y_factor, test_size = 0.20)
scaler_model = MinMaxScaler()
scaler_model.fit(x_train)

x_train=pd.DataFrame(scaler_model.transform(x_train),columns=x_train.columns,index=x_train.index)

scaler_model.fit(x_test)

x_eval=pd.DataFrame(scaler_model.transform(x_test),columns=x_test.columns,index=x_test.index)

#Creating Feature Columns\
feat_cols=[]\
for cols in x_factors:\
    column=tf.feature_column.numeric_column(cols)\
    feat_cols.append(column)\

#The estimator model\
model=tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[6,10,6],feature_columns=feat_cols)

#the input function
input_func=tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x_train,y_train,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)

#Training the model
model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=1000)
```

Problem arises when I train the model:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
        325   try:
    --> 326     fn(values)
        327   except ValueError as e:
    
    22 frames
    ValueError: Tensor("random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:14", shape=(None,), dtype=float64, device=/device:CPU:0)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
        328     [mismatch] = e.args
        329     if dtype is None:
    --> 330       raise TypeError("Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.")
        331     else:
        332       raise TypeError(f"Expected {dtype.name}, but got {mismatch} of type "
    
    TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.
```

Any help for this?

Comment: `input_func=tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x_train,y_train,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)`
You are using compat to older version of tensorflow 1.0, which used eager processing, though tensorflow 2.0+ uses tensors. So, you should try to use TFv2 or make your data eager